# Problema al visualizar registros por medio de axios en laravel

Tags: laravel, axios

Actualmente intento crear un crud con ventanas modales e intento registrar y para realizar tal registro uso axios desde vue js.

El problema es el siguiente:

Cuando selecciono de la tabla un empleado de la vista, me muestra en una ventana modal el nombre y el boton actualizar, luego realizo la modificacion y el método update del controlador si realiza el cambio en la base de datos, y para que la vista donde tengo los registros refresque los cambios le paso el:

```
return redirect()->route('gestion-empleados.index');
```

Pero cuando me redireccionar de nuevo a la vista, no se visualiza los cambios, y tengo que cargar de nuevo la pagina y se visualiza, me imagino que debo recargar la pagina con codigo e intente pasarle el   window.location.reload();

```
 axios.put(url,this.vue.datoNombre).then(response=>{
                               this.vue.datoNombre= {'idEmpleado':'','nombre':''};  
window.location.reload();
                       });
```

como se muestra en el código de arriba en axios.put no refresca la pagina. Alguien sabe que esta pasando o que estoy haciendo mal?

Como pueden observar este es el codigo que utilizo para actualizar el registro. Un dato importante es que en el servidor local funciona, pero no en un hosting y si llega funcionar es cuando recargo la pagina se visualiza los datos en una tabla.

```
actualizarNombre:function(){
                 if(this.vue.datoNombre.length !== 0){
                   var url = 'gestion-empleados/'+this.vue.datoNombre.idEmpleado;
                   axios.put(url,this.vue.datoNombre).then(response=>{
                           this.vue.datoNombre= {'idEmpleado':'','nombre':''};
                   });
                 }
               },
```

Mi controlador para realizar la actualización

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id){
    {

      $empleado= Empleado::find($id);
      $empleado->nombre = $request->nombre;
      if($empleado->save()){
        Session::flash('registrado','Se ha actualizado los datos  de la empleado');
      }
    }
    return redirect()->route('gestion-empleados.index');
    }
```

Comment: Si necesitas refrescar la pagina, ¿por que usas AJAX en lugar de enviarlo simplemente por formulario?

Comment: Pues no encontré información de hacerlo como tu dices haciendo uso de ventanas modales

Comment: Puedes añadir un formulario post en una ventana modal sin problemas, aunque si lo que necesitas es que se refresque solo la ventana modal con datos, entonces habra que hacer algunas cositas.

Comment: Si lo hago como tu dices como le pasaria los datos de envio? {!! Form::model($empleado,['route'=>['updateempleado.update',$empleado->idEmpleado],'method'=>'PUT','id'=>'formEdit']) !!} fue esto que no supe como hacerlo, anteriormente hice otros crud pero sin ventana modal y a cada formulario para editar la información lepasaba esa linea

Comment: Pues no estoy muy puesto en Form Helper, pero basicamente prepara el formulario normal, el action del formulario que sea la url donde lo envias, y el method PUT. A los inputs dale los name que necesites, y usa un submit para enviarlo